# How to call the subscribe error block in unit testing Angular?

Tags: angular, jestjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

i have tried unit testing in Angular subscribe, i write below testcase but its not 100% reach not accessin error block section

componant

```
   this.Servive.methof(value).subscribe(res => {
   
    this.router.navigate('url');
  },
  error => {
    this.error= true;
  });
```

spec file

```
   const spy = jest.spyOn(servive, 'method').mockReturnValue(of(appDataCreateResponse));
   component.dunction();
    expect(spy).Error(); 
    expect(component.apiError).toBeTruthy;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
....
const spy = jest.spyOn(servive, 'method').mockReturnValue(throwError({}));
   component.dunction();
    expect(component.error).toBe(true);
```